How to Add a Server Connection to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
I have an old machine that has been correctly connected to a server that has a database on it. I have a new computer that I am trying to connect to the same server and database. The old laptop has under "Database Engine" a list of servers (ex. "COMNAME\MSSQLSERVER").  Here is a screenshot of SSMS on my new laptop. I am not understanding how you connect a server to SSMS and have it show up on this list.


Surely you want Network Servers, not Local Servers, no?

"I am not understanding how you connect a server to SSMS" Why are you unable to type the server name into the "Server Name" textbox? Connecting to SQL Server from your new machine is no different to your old machine; why do you think it would be different?

That list, as the label says, is Local Servers.
If you are trying to connect to a server elsewhere, you need to enter the server name in the previous dialogue.  Unless SSMS is on the same machine as the SQL Server, it will never show up in the Local Servers list.

